extract instrumental variables Error in if (out == "[]") { : argument is of length zero
I can extract instrumental variables from dataset 'ieu-a-2' using code below:
exp_dat <- extract_instruments(outcomes = 'ieu-a-2')

But it is strange that I can not extract IVs from dataset 'ukb-b-7372' using code below:
exp_dat <- extract_instruments(outcomes = 'ukb-b-7372')

Error occurs as below:
Error in if (out == "[]") { : argument is of length zero

I wish someone can help me to fix this error. I don't know why this happens.T_T

you should report this as a bug with the authors of the package with extract_instruments()

for your purposes, look at traceback() after the error to get a better idea of what's going wrong, then try debug() for the function throwing the error. it's likely the instrument you requested isn't found.
